# Is there a way to select rows in database per day?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to create a sql request which returns the employees with 0 absence and with 0 hours worked per day between an interval choosen by an user. I got my view v_personnel (rows about the employees), exp_mat_abs (rows about absence of my employee) and exp_mat_mo (rows about the worked hours of the employees). I am stuck. I don't find the way how i can get the employees with 0 absence and with 0 hours worked per day between an interval choosen by an user.
Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: Sample data with expected result will help

Comment: For exemple one employee who doesn't have worked hours and 0 absence, the request result should be :
id_employee : 04020, name : webber, day: 01/01/2019

Comment: I can join my view to exp_mat_mo and exp_mat_abs whith the id_employee but i don't know how to have the request result for each day between a start day and an end day

Comment: please use the "edit" button to add relevant information  to the question itself, rather than using the comments. Then it's much clearer and more coherent for everyone. Thanks.

Comment: @QuentinSorin . . . Sample data and desired results should be included as *text* tables in the question, not as comments.  As the author, you can edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a record on the employees table for each employee, but there will be no Record in hours worked or hours absent if the non working employee was not absent. Aside from the slight contradiction in how someone can not work but also not be absent :) (I assume you mean they're on some kind of no-work-no-pay deal) what you want is

```
employees 
left join hoursworked on ... 
left join absent on ...
```

Employees that are zero absent/hours will have NULL in every column from each of the hours/absence tables

If you just want these employees you can

```
WHERE hoursworkedtable.primarykeycolumnname IS NULL
```

If you want to turn the null into zero you can:

```
SELECT COALESCE(somenullcolumn, 0) as somenullcolumn
```

The only other thing I wanted to point out is that hours worked and hours absent aren't necessarily related concepts - you might want to group them up into eg a time period before you join and join on the employee and the day also, otherwise you'll end up with a Cartesian product - basically find some way of reducing the rows coming out of the worked and absence tables so there is only one row from each per employee (per time period) before you join:

```
employees 
left join (select ... from hoursworked group by...) on ... 
left join (select ... from absent group by...)  on ...
```

If you don't, then multiple rows from either of them, per employee, will cause data from the other table to duplicate

Edit; so you need some extra days per employee:

```
employee e
cross join
generate_series('2019-01-10'::timestamp, '2019-01-21'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) d
left outer join (select emp, thedate, ... from hoursworked group by emp, thedate) w
on w.empid = e.empid and w.thedate = d.d
left outer join (select emp, thedate, ... from absent group by emp, thedate) a
on a.empid = e.empid and a.thedate = d.d
```

we ask generate_series to make us a list of dates between the 10th and the 21st, and join the employees to it. This gives us a per-employee-per-day thing. Now we can left join our hours and absences onto this and get hours worked per day (or null if they didnt work) and absences per day (or null if they weren't absent)

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to generate "fake days"

Comment: What is your d.d, i don't get it ?

Comment: It's the output of generate_series. Paste this into your pgsql: `SELECT d.d FROM generate_series('2019-01-10'::timestamp, '2019-01-21'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) d` and run it, you'll see that generate_series is like a table, I aliased it `d`. both the table name and the column name it generates end up called the same. It generates 1 column, of data, called `d` in a table also called `d` hence `d.d`

Comment: this request will give me the employees without worked hours and without absences ?
 select v.id,v.nom,v.prenom,v.etablissement,v.categorie,d.d
from v_personnel v
Cross join generate_series('2019-01-10'::timestamp, '2019-01-21'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) d
left outer join (select id_intervenant,id_jour from exp_chantier_mo group by id_intervenant, id_jour) w
on w.id_intervenant = v.id and w.id_jour = d.d
left outer join (select id_intervenant, id_jour from exp_chantier_absence group by id_intervenant, id_jour) a
on a.id_intervenant = v.id and a.id_jour = d.d
WHERE v.salarie=true

Comment: Looks reasonable, so long as id_jour is a date, and not a number/guid like IDs usually are! :)

Comment: id_jour is a date (not my database, that's quiet weird i admit it) but this request didn't return me only my employee without absences and worked hours

Comment: If you only want employees with NULLs in worked/absences, you need to consider `WHERE v.salarie = true AND (a.id_intervenant IS NULL OR v.id_intervenant IS NULL)` perhaps? (Mentioned it at the top of my answer). Do a `SELECT *` and take a look a the data - pick what you want as a result, and find a way of expressing it as a WHERE clause

Comment: I think that this is working but i am not sure enough, thank you for your time and your help. Have a nice day ;)